# changing the process of registration

Tags: users, emails

I need to make a different process for user registration in drupal.
1] set username, email and password.
2] send a verification email to user's email address.
3] by clicking on the link in the email direct to the site as a logged in user.

I mean I need to set password in the first step, not after clicking on the link in the email. although It's a bit illogical but users would be less confused in this way.

if there is a module for this please let me know otherwise I need to change it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

[User registration password](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_registrationpassword).
This is the first result when searching "drupal user registration password" on google.

Comment: this module is not properly! when I click on the activation link in email I face with a 403 page!!!! what is wrong about this module?

Comment: Did you read the [README](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/user_registrationpassword/tree/README.txt) file about configuration? Also, a patch has been [committed](https://www.drupal.org/node/1050930/commits) for compatability with the latest versions of drupal, so it might be better to use the dev version. There are nearly 6000 installs of this module so the problem is obviously with your setup, not the module.

Comment: I have read the readme file although its configuration is clear and does not need to point anyway. also none of the issues are related to this one